# How to check if tabindex has focus?

Tags: javascript, html

**Here is my code**

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($packages); $i++) {?>
    <div id="pack" class="bg_package" tabindex="<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <input hidden id="ind" class="bg_package" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"/>
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Here is script**

```
document.onkeyup = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
var tabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
   e = e || window.event;
   if (e.keyCode == '39') {
       $('[tabindex=' + tabindex + ']').focus();
       $("div.bg_package").eq(index).css("border", "2px solid #0077ff");
       tabindex++;
       console.log('rigth arrow pressed')
    } 
 }
```

But When I click `right arrow`, no change. I don't know what to do. It should be activated by right-clicking on something without first clicking on it.

Comment: Not all browsers establish a `window.event`.  It's not standard behavior to make the event global.  Instead you need to use `addEventHandler` to make a non-inline event binding that will **always** pass in the event as the argument

Comment: Working on tags such as input, p, etc., except tabindex. @Taplar

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that that is not standard behavior for all browsers.

Comment: Also `tabindex` is not a tag.  It's an attribute.  So saying it works on `input` and `p`, but not tabindex, is a strange comparison